# How do I visit consequent result pages at wigle.net using Mechanize?

Tags: perl, mechanize

I have the following code which uses the [`WWW::Mechanize`](http://p3rl.org/WWW::Mechanize) and [`HTML::TableExtract`](http://p3rl.org/HTML::TableExtract) modules. Everything works like a charm, except that I'm not capable of moving to the next pages. I'm trying to get a list of hotspots from http://www.wigle.net/gps/gps/main. The UserID is `natty_a`, the password is `natty`. Click on `[searching]`, and then on `Query`.

My script should accept coordinates and data and bring that table. It does that, but only for the first page. It seems like I cannot move to the next pages, cannot click on the `Next100 >>` button.

I tried the following solutions, to no avail:

```
$mech_browser->post(
    'https://wigle.net/gps/gps/main/confirmquery/', [
        pagestart => $i,
        Query     => 'Next100 >>'
    ]
)
```

`$mech_browser` is a `WWW::Mechanize` instance and `i` is just the number of results to get. I used [Live HTTP Headers](http://livehttpheaders.mozdev.org/) to find it out.

```
$mech_browser->click_button(value => 'Next100 >>')
```

This does not work, either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a very cool module, [`WWW::Mechanize::Shell`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/WWW-Mechanize-Shell/), which allows one to interactively play with a page, click various buttons etc.
Once a satisfactory result is reached, one can generate a Perl script that uses `WWW::Mechanize` and that performs precisely the actions that one has performed while playing.

Then what is left is to edit out actions which are not needed from the generated script.

I'd suggest you use that to find your solution.

Comment: Ok, I'm one step further, now I have no idea how to select form 2, I have this forms (using the shell module, and 'forms' command): Form [1] POST wigle.net/gps/gps/main/confirmquery pagestart=0 (hidden readonly) Query=<< Previous 100 (submit) Form [2] POST wigle.net/gps/gps/main/confirmquery pagestart=200 (hidden readonly) Query=Next100 >> (submit) I want to perform 'click' on form 2, I can select form 2 (according to the module doc) only by its name, I dont see the name, any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure you need:

```
$mech->submit_form(
    form_number => 1,
    button => "Query",
);
```

But if you on the second page the form_number should be 2 (because first form is for "Previous" button).